# I am not able to deploy website on heroku using heroku and git cli

Tags: git, github, heroku

I deployed my website on heroku but I made an error in Procfile. Which I came to know later but now I am not able to correct it. Pls help me with it
Firstly I used
`git add .`
Then I used
`git commit -m "Second Commit"`
Finally I used
`git push heroku master`
It shows no-update

What shall I do?